# How to use EnvironmentObjects in AppDelegate with SwiftUI?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication, appdelegate

I am trying to access some environment objects in my AppDelegate. I am using an addStateDidChangeListener to see if the Firebase user's token is valid or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Auth.auth().useAppLanguage()
    
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        
        if let user = user {
            
            user.getIDTokenResult { result, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Could not get the ID token result: \(error)")
                    self.sessionExpired()
                }
                
                if let expirationDate = result?.expirationDate {
                    
                    if Date() >= expirationDate {
                        print("Login session has expired.")
                        self.sessionExpired()
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Could not get the expiration date from the ID token result.")
                    self.sessionExpired()
                }
                
            }
            
        } else {
            print("No user is signed in.")
        }
        
    }
    return true
}
```

If the token is not valid or the user does not exist, I am showing a UIAlertController which says that they need to sign in again.

```
func sessionExpired() {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Session Expired.", message: "Your login session has expired. Please sign in again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        
        FirebaseFunctions.signOutOfFirebase(saveAt: self.viewContext, with: self.environmentObjects, with: self.mapInformation, deleteCoreData: true)
        
    }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
    
}
```

When they press the OK button, I have to run a function. The functions is called `FirebaseFunctions.signOutOfFirebase(saveAt: self.viewContext, with: self.environmentObjects, with: self.mapInformation, deleteCoreData: true)` which takes 3 parameters. Two of them are environment objects, named `environmentObjects` and the `mapInformation`.

Whenever the function is called however, I get the error:

> Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type EnvironmentObjects found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for EnvironmentObjects may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

This is where my app's life cycle begins:

```
@main
struct MainApp: App {

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate: AppDelegate

@StateObject var environmentObjects = EnvironmentObjects()
@StateObject var networkMonitor = NetworkMonitor()
@StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
@StateObject var mapInformation = MapInformation()
@StateObject var popRoot = PopRoot()

... code
```

How do I pass the environment objects to my AppDelegate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have `let` variables in the `AppDelegate` instead of those `@StateObject` then inject using `.environmentObject(appDelegate.environmentObjects)` for the rest of the Views

Comment: Why not declare as @StateObject inside the AppDelegate?

Comment: Why do you use `AppDelegate` at all? The code is not related to received data of any delegate method or any other code which must be run in AppDelegate. You can run the code also in a ViewModel.

Comment: StateObject only works in SwiftUI views

Comment: @vadian, I am using AppDelegate in order to configure Firebase

Comment: It's not required to configure Firebase in `AppDelegate`, you can do it everywhere

Answer (score -1):

I do think that `@EnvironmentObject` is a SwiftUI wrapper for passing data between **views**.
I strongly encourage you to take a look at Paul's Hudson article here [How to use @EnvironmentObject to share data between views](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)

> Note: Environment objects must be supplied by an ancestor view – if SwiftUI can’t find an environment object of the correct type you’ll get a crash. This applies for previews too, so be careful.

Sounds familiar, right?

There is also a second article: [What is the @EnvironmentObject property wrapper?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-environmentobject-property-wrapper) I like this *forced unwrapped optionals* comparison:

> Warning: When a view using @EnvironmentObject is shown, SwiftUI will immediately search the environment for an object of the correct type. If such an object can’t be found – i.e., if you forgot to place it in the environment – then your app will immediately crash. When you use @EnvironmentObject you are effectively promising that object will exist in the environment by the time it is needed, a bit like using implicitly unwrapped optionals.

If you want to see some code-examples, I would recommend CodeWithChris YouTube video [Data Flow in a SwiftUI App](https://youtu.be/jD6c9y8CFGQ?t=1592)

PS. would you please tell where you want to use those `@StateObject` variables? Usually I instantiate `private var myObject: Type = Type()` within `@main` struct and then pass it to the view using `.environmentObject(myObject)` modifier.